# Function Break Out of For Loop Unexpectedly in Python

Tags: python, function

I'm still a beginner when it comes to Python. I've most recently attempted the 2nd Project Euler question regarding fibonacci numbers, and unfortunately I am stuck. On a simple for-loop, no less. Within this for-loop I attempt to assign the returned result of a function to a variable, and whether or not said variable matches a condition, a total is increased. However, this loop only runs once before it exits, and I am absolutely perplexed. I'm at the end of my wits; if any of you can help to correct this issue I would be grateful. Below is the relevant portion of my code:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        x = n - 1
        y = n - 2
        return x + y

num = input("Input your number of choice: ")
total = 0
```

The problem area:

```
for i in range(int(num)):
    val = fibonacci(i)
    if (val % 2 == 0):
        total = total + val

print(total)
```

Comment: How can you tell that it's only running once?

Comment: Thats not how you do fibonacci.  You probably want to do `return fibonacci(x) + fibonacci(y)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will only calculate `total = total + val` once, when `val = 0` , for all other cases, your fibonacci function is returning `2*n -3` which is always odd number, but you are checking if the returned val is `even` (which it would never be except for when 0) , and hence the issue.

Maybe you wanted to return something like -

```
return fibonacci(x) + fibonacci(y) # or the simpler , fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the sequence `Fn` of [Fibonacci numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) is defined by the recurrence relation `F_n = F_{n-1} + F_{n-2}`.

**Option 1: Using recursion**

Instead of `return (n-1) + (n-2)`, it should be `return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)`.

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        x = fibonacci(n-1)
        y = fibonacci(n-2)
        return x + y

num = input("Input your number of choice: ")

print(fibonacci(num))
```

Here is an example:

```
$ python fibonacci.py
Input your number of choice: 11
89
```

**Option 2: Using loop**

```
def fibonacci(num):
 a,b = 1,1
 for i in range(num-1):
  a,b = b,a+b
 return a

print fibonacci(num)
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue I see is you are trying to print a variable that was assigned in a `for` loop. Instead, you can do...

```
for i in range(int(num)):
     val = fibonacci(i)
     if (val % 2 == 0):
         return (total + val)
```

Comment: OP does `total = 0` outside the loop.

Comment: "When that loop ends, so does that variable" -- No, it doesn't.